# extract lines from bottom until regex match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, regular-expression

I have this output.

```
[root@linux ~]# cat /tmp/file.txt
virt-top time  11:25:14 Host foo.example.com x86_64 32/32CPU 1200MHz 65501MB
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0  95:44:07 instance-00000372
virt-top time  11:25:17 Host foo.example.com x86_64 32/32CPU 1200MHz 65501MB
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

You can see it has two blocks and i want to extract last block (if you see first block it has all CPU zero which i don't care) inshort i want to extract following last lines (Notes: sometime i have more than two instance-*) otherwise i could use "tail -n 2"

```
1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

I have tried sed/awk/grep and all possible way but not get close to desire result.

Comment: It can help us help you if you provide some of your "all possible ways" you tried

Comment: I think i am closed `sed '1,/instance/p' /tmp/foo.txt` still its printing header line which is `ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME` i can trim it down with `| grep -v ID` but i believe there must be better way :)

Comment: How about extracting all lines with non-zero CPU-Uage like (untested) `grep -vE -e virt-top -e RDRQ -e "([^ ]*  *){6}0.0"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feels a bit silly, but:

```
$ tac file.txt |sed -e '/^virt-top/q' |tac
virt-top time  11:25:17 Host foo.example.com x86_64 32/32CPU 1200MHz 65501MB
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

GNU `tac` reverses the file (many non-GNU systems have `tail -r` instead), the `sed` picks lines until the first that starts with `virt-top`. You can add `sed 1,2d` or `tail -n +3` to remove the headers.

Or in awk:

```
$ awk '/^virt-top/ { a = "" } { a = a $0 ORS } END {printf "%s", a}' file.txt 
virt-top time  11:25:17 Host foo.example.com x86_64 32/32CPU 1200MHz 65501MB
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

It just collects all the lines to a variable, and clears that variable on a line starting with `virt-top`.

If the file is very large, the `tac`+`sed` solution is bound to be faster since it only needs to read the tail end of the file while the `awk` solution reads the full file from the top.

Comment: Only the `tac` solution is practical if `file.txt` is very large and the match is (as expected) towards its end. Also, it could be better written as `tac file.txt | sed '/^virt-top/q' | tac`

Comment: I really like `tac` first time i heard :D

Comment: @mosvy, excellent points, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With `ed` you can regex-search *upward* using `?pattern?` in place of the usual `/pattern/` (which searches from above the current position). So for example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '?ID?+1,$p' q | ed -s file.txt
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

Comment: very simple and sweet, didn't thought about `printf` can run the show :)

Comment: `ed` sucks with very large files.

Comment: ... because it reads the whole file into a buffer in memory before operating on it.

Comment: @Ed, I suppose it depends on the implementation, but at least GNU `ed`, while it reads the file fully, doesn't store it whole in memory (probably only records the offsets of each line within the file which explains why it's more efficient at dealing with longer lines). It does create a temporary copy of the file though.

Answer (score 3):

If your input has a fixed number of blocks you could also do something like:

```
awk '/^virt-top/ && ++n == 2, 0' <your-file
```

To output the lines from the 2<sup>nd</sup> occurrence of `virt-top` to the end of the file (0 meaning *false*, means the end of that *first*,*last* range is never found).

Answer (score 1):

Getting the last record from the line that starts with the string `virt-top` to the end using `ed` (suitable for dealing with files of the size comparable with what you show, not several megabytes big):

```
$ printf '%s\n' '?^virt-top?,$p' | ed -s file
virt-top time  11:25:17 Host foo.example.com x86_64 32/32CPU 1200MHz 65501MB
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

Or, just the lines after the last `virt-top` line that contain the substring `instance`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '?^virt-top?,$g/instance/p' | ed -s file
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

That last `ed` command, `?^virt-top?,$g/instance/p`, first designates a range of lines from the last line that starts with `virt-top` (last, because `ed` starts you off on the last line of the buffer and `?re?` searches backwards) to the end of the buffer (`$`) and applies the command `g/instance/p` to these lines.  The `g/re/p` command prints all lines within the range that matches the given regular expression (that's where `grep` got its name from, by the way).

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^virt-top/ { lines = "" } /instance/ { lines = (lines == "" ? $0 : lines ORS $0) } END { print lines }' file
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

This saves lines of input in `lines` whenever there's a line that contains the substring `instance`.  These lines are printed at the end.  Whenever a line that starts with `virt-top` is found, the saved lines are discarded.

Virtually the same thing with `sed`, using the hold space to serve as the equivalent of the `lines` variable in the `awk` code:

```
$ sed -n '/^virt-top.*/{ s///; x; d; }; /instance/H; ${ x; s/\n//; p; }' file
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
    2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/540029/extract-lines-from-bottom-until-regex-match#comment1001976_540030

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another method to deal with it:

```
$ sed -e '
   /\n/q
   /virt-top/{h;d;}
   H;$!d;g
   s/\n//;D
' file.txt
```

**Results**

```
1 R    0    0    0    0  0.6 12.0  96:02:53 instance-0000036f
2 R    0    0    0    0  0.2 12.0  95:44:08 instance-00000372
```